# JavaFX - Drag and Drop rows from one TableView to another

Tags: java, events, drag-and-drop, javafx, tableview

I'm sorry for this noob question but my head is spinning from reading all sorts of code and book samples, I still don't know how to do this.

I've made an **FXML** app and put **TableViews**, the source (**MainDB**) and the targets (table1, 2, 3). The **MainDB** loads stuff from a database. I want to Drag'N'Drop rows of data from the **MainDB** to table1.

What my simple mind thinks I should do in the Controller class is this:
a) on **MainDB** when **OnDragDetected**, store the row in a temp var

```
temp = source.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
```

b) on target when **OnDragDropped**, add temp in a ObservableList which in turn is added to the target.

The code i have in my Controller is this:

```
@FXML
private void copyFromSource(MouseEvent event) {

    mainDB.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Copying works");
            temp = new Item(mainDB.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        }
    });
}

@FXML
private void addToTarget(MouseDragEvent event) {

    table1.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            tempList.add(temp);
            table1.setItems(toCopyList);
            toCopyList.clear();
        }
    });
}
```

I'm still struggling to understand how I should structure my code and the **MVC** in **JavaFX FXML** is a bit tricky to me. Events are a lot trickier and I'm really baffled right now.

**EDIT**: I managed to fire the first event, **copyFromSource** is called and the event fires. But not **addToTarget**. I've either messed up the events there or I'm doing it entirely wrong.